# Angularjs assign value into controller after getting output in directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I am very new to angularjs and googlemaps please help me out.

My html file:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="carLocationCtrl">

    <div my-map=""></div>
    <p>{{myCurrentPosition}}</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="E:\Projects\Angular Projects\angularmap.js"></script>

</body>
```

Here i want to get value of my currentPosition from directive then pass or assign that value into my controller variable myCurrentLocation.then only i can able to show this value in my `<p>` tag.

My Controller :

```
    var OEMControllers=angular.module('myApp',[]);

    OEMControllers.controller('carLocationCtrl', ["$scope", "$rootScope", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.isEditLocation = false;
    $scope.myCurrentLocation='';
    $scope.saveCarLocation = function () {
        $scope.isEditLocation = true;
    };
    $scope.editCarLocation = function () {
        $scope.isEditLocation = false;
    };
    }]).directive('myMap', function() {

    var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var map, infoWindow;
        var markers = [];

        // map config
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(50, 2),
            zoom: 4,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false
        };

        // init the map
        function initMap() {
            if (map === void 0) {
                map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);
            }
        }    

        // place a marker
        function setMarker(map, position) {
            var marker;
            var markerOptions = {
                position: position,
                center:position,
                map: map,
                icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
            };

            marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
            markers.push(marker); // add marker to array

            //pan to marker..
            console.log('marker.getPosition() :: '+marker.getPosition());
             map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
            map.setZoom(16);
             console.log('pan called');

    //here i can able to get my currentPosition but how can i send this value to my controller .........

    scope.myCurrentLocation=marker.getPosition();

    console.log('output :: '+scope.myCurrentLocation);

        }

        // show the map and place some markers
        initMap();
        getLocation();

        var watchID=null;
        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);

                /* var options = { timeout: 30000 };
                    watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);*/

        } else { 
                console.log('Not obtain geolocation');
        }
    }

    //geolocation succes..

        function onSuccess(position) {

            console.log('lat :: '+position.coords.latitude);
            console.log('long :: '+position.coords.longitude);


                setMarker(map, new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
                }

                function onError(error)
                {
                    console.log(error.message);
                }

    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div id="gmaps"></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: link
    };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

- assign the value to the scope object. (I think you have done that in the code).
- angular uses cascading/extending scopes so any controller that is declared in a child element can still read the value you have assigned. You may access them directly by ng-model or ng-bind.
- you may want to instantiate a service/value (singleton) and make the directive as well as the controller depend on it. Now the value you assign in a directive is accessible to all those that depend on the service/value.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code it ok but in your html you have used wrong variable name like "myCurrentPosition" and i think it will work with "myCurrentLocation"

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to add a isolated scope to your 'myMap' directive, and take the reference of 'myCurrentLocation' from the controller to the directive as follows:

The link function would return as below:

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div id="gmaps"></div>',
    replace: true,
    scope : {
        location : "="
    }
    link: link
};
```

In the directive link function, wherever you change the marker position save the position in the directive scope as below.( Make sure you use the attribute name which you have used in the isolated scope in the step above):

```
scope.location=marker.getPosition();
```

And your html file will look like:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="carLocationCtrl">

    <div my-map="" location="myCurrentLocation"></div>
    <p>{{myCurrentLocation}}</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="E:\Projects\Angular Projects\angularmap.js"></script>

</body>
```